# Catch panning event in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is it possible to catch event when user is panning on chart?

I've Highcharts options set to:

```
chart: {
  panning: true,
  panKey: 'shift',
  events: {}
}
```

In events object, *selection* is working. In the documentation, there's nothing about *pane* event.

Is there a way to catch this event anyway?

Comment: Can you catch shift-events on the document itself? Is that workable on your page? It isn;t the correct event, but if shift also triggers panning you could use it

Comment: Indeed it could work, but imagine there's a text input where user want to type something. I'm wondering if it's a part of Highcharts API to get drag&drop or move event

Comment: And adding a container div to your chart and catch shift events inside this container?

Comment: I imagine your last proposition is possible, but I'd really like an integrated event (if exists)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Highcharts doesn't provide that kind of event by default.

The workaround for this is to **wrap** the core `pan` function:

```
(function(H) {
  H.wrap(H.Chart.prototype, 'pan', function(proceed) {
    console.log("panning...");
    proceed.call(this, arguments[1], arguments[2]);
  });
})(Highcharts);
```

---

**Live demo:** 
http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/gn8gmsn0/

**Docs reference:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts

Comment: Its possible to define Pan events now 

`chart: {
    type: 'line',
    zoomType: 'x',
    panning: true,
    panKey: 'shift',

    events: {
      selection: (e) => {
        console.log('selection event', e);
      },
      pan: (e) => {
       console.log('pan event', e);
      },      
    },
  },`